# jQuery mustache.js template in file

Tags: mustache

Is it ok to do this inside the same template file:

```
    <script id="events_calendar_template" type="text/html">
    {{#events}}
        <h1>{{EventTitle}}</h1>
        <h2>{{EventDate}}{{#ShowTimes}} - {{EventStartTime}} - {{EventEndTime}}{{/ShowTimes}}</h2>
        <h3>{{CategoryName}}</h3>
        <p>{{EventLongDescription}}</p>
    {{/events}}
    </script>

    <div id="events_calendar_holder"></div>
```

Rendering html:

```
var view = {events:events};

$("#events_calendar_holder").html($.mustache($("#events_calendar_template").html(), view)).hide().fadeIn('slow');
```